# SQS - getting the number of message in every queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I need to present list of queues and the number of messages for each queue, something similar to the SQS dashboard.

In the API there are 2 relevant calls. The first is ListQueues, and GetQueueAttributes. So that for every queue that appears in ListQueues I can get the number of messages. BUT I'm looking for a way to do it in one call.

Is there away of doing it?

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 1):

No.

You will need to `list_queues()` to obtain a list of `QueueUrls`, then call `get_queue_attributes()` to obtain a count from each queue.